# IBM mobileFirst IOS application screen blackout after direct update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, direct-update

Details of Project :

- Application Framework - Ionic V3.0
- IBM MobileFirst server(devKit)   - Product version: 8.0.0.00-20170911-123510
- Application Mobilefirst version -
  config.xml -

  mfp:platformVersion -8.0.0.00-20170218-003050

  plugin name="cordova-plugin-mfp" spec="8.0.2017021815"

It's working fine in android. But in IOS, after finishing of soft update, application screen goes blank (black screen). After killing and restart of application, it's started working fine.

I have implement `Direct update` feature in mobilefirst 8 application as below :

```
// Direct Update - Used to trigger a request to the MobileFirst Server, to check for updated web resources. 
WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
.then(
 function () {
   console.log("*** Obtained token successfully.");
 },
 function () {
   console.log("*** Failed obtaining token.");
 }
);
```

Reference : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/#secure-direct-update

Comment: Can you try your app built with latest version of `cordova-plugin-mfp` plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed in latest IBM MobileFirst version.

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps has to do with the fact that Ionic now uses the WKWebView by default. See https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/

And it is a known limitation with MobileFirst Direct update on the WKWebview. See https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/release-notes/known-issues-limitations/#wkwebview-support-for-ios-cordova-applications

As mentioned in the above link, use the wkwebview-engine-localhost plugin to ensure Direct update continues to work.

Comment: The cordova plugin suggested as solution, is not installing. It is causing issue.